# Android : Need help in implementing ACRA

Tags: java, android, acra

I am new to Android development. I am trying to implement ACRA for error reporting purpose. I have written following code to integrate ACRA within the project.

```
   @ReportsCrashes 
   (
    formKey = "",
    reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
    formUri = "localhost:5984/acra-mediwatch/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
    formUriBasicAuthLogin = "admin",
    formUriBasicAuthPassword = "admin"        
    )
```

The problem is it's working fine locally but server URL (e.g. 208.109.91.98:5984 instead of localhost:5984) when specified gives me following error:

```
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979): Failed to send crash report for 1391489780000-approved.stacktrace
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979): org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending JSON report via Http PUT
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:228)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979): Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /208.109.91.98:5984 timed out
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:152)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
02-04 04:56:24.741: E/ACRA(979):    ... 3 more
```

I am not able to guess from this log where I am going wrong. Any ideas regarding how can I make it work for server? Help appreciated.

Comment: `/208.109.91.98:5984 timed out` -- your server is not responding, or you wrote the URL incorrectly. Please include the full URL instead of localhost.

Comment: I am specifying URL like this:

formUri = "http://208.109.91.98:5984/acra-medicare/_design/acra-storage/_update/report"

Is it correct @323go ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, why is it timing out for your device?

Does it have a net connection? Perhaps you need to increase the ACRA SocketTimeout config. I think default is 3000 or 5000 millis. If you increase that to 10,000 millis does it help?

More detail [here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/9)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Md Abdul Gafur. I have make sure that net connection in on. I also increased SocketTimeout but no luck..!

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to the form written correctly? DId you remember to add these two permissions in the manifest?:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```